# Test docker locally on postman

Tags: node.js, docker, postman, serverless-framework

My setup is as follows:

I am running a serverless framework with Node.js as my backend. I am trying to build a docker image that executes a serverless-offline plugin to run the server locally.

**Docker**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:10

# Set the working directory of the docker image 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001

ENTRYPOINT [ "./node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless", "offline", "start", "--port", "3001", "--stage", "prerelease","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--noauth" ]
CMD ["lib/functions/generateDoc/index.handler"]
```

When executing the following command `docker run -p 3001:3001 -it docdownload`, the output shows as

```
Serverless: Starting Offline: prerelease/us-west-2.


Serverless: Routes for generateDoc:

Serverless: POST /exportDoc

Serverless: WARNING: Serverless Offline does not support non local authorizers (authorizerId): [object Object]

Serverless: POST /{apiVersion}/functions/doc-api-prerelease-generateDoc/invocations


Serverless: Offline [HTTP] listening on http://localhost:3001

Serverless: Enter "rp" to replay the last request
```

However, when I am trying to hit API using Postman, I am seeing this
[image]

How to test this docker server locally using postman?

Comment: How do you run the container and what do you see in its logs, after you used postman?

Comment: I am using this `docker run -p 3001:3001 -it docdownload` to run docker. I don't see any logs, that's the problem. There is no connection at all.

Comment: the thing is listening on localhost, thats only available inside the container. You need to bind the private network interface or 0.0.0.0 for that matter.

Comment: What "The Fool" said is wrong. You are exposing the 3001 port on the host using the `-p` flag, so this should work. You can view the logs with `docker logs <container_name>`. If you can't find the container name (using: `docker ps`) then add a `-name mycontainername` flag to the `run` command.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, what I am saying is not wrong. If you listen inside the container on localhost, the publish flag does not help you. The log message of the container says `Serverless: Offline [HTTP] listening on http://localhost:3001`. If you are in doubt, you can try it out with some toy app. In fact, its one of the most common issues around docker you will find here on SO. That said, whats weird about it is that in the entrypoint `--host 0.0.0.0` is provided but the log message still reports localhost.

Comment: I tried `docker logs <container name>`, and it end up showing the output I pasted above.

Comment: Yeah, true, although I am saying host to be `0.0.0.0` , it is somehow showing `localhost`

Comment: what module is this, `serverless`? can you link to the github repo or documentation?

Comment: Yeah, sure, `https://github.com/serverless/serverless`